# Unflatten JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON response, I want to unflatten it, but every possible unflatten library just append it to array, I want to  highlight to have 3 object like shown, is there any easier way?

```
{
    "highlights.id": ["9ab80883-e8eb-4710-9818-e476fc32e356", "824ff2a0-1f17-44b7-b99f-ce227af12ea7", "4a9e35c5-e03f-41d6-a4b5-635b08bc1bbe", ],
    "highlights.key": ["0", "1", "2"],
    "highlights.value": ['16" Pedestal Fan', "High Quality Metal Grill ", "Heavy Duty Motor with 2000 RPM", ],
    "highlights.productId": ["655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", ],
    "highlights.createdAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ],
    "highlights.updatedAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ]
}
```

I want something like

`highlights:[ {// id, key, value, productId}, {}, {}]`

But I'm getting

`highlights:{ id:[], productId:[], key:[], value:[]`

Comment: Are the keys in your JSON object constant or can the keys change ?

Comment: Also, are you looking for `1. highlights:[ {// id, key, value, productId}, {}, {}]` or `2. highlights:[ {id: idvalue, key: keyvalue, value: value, productId: value}, {}, {}]` ?

Comment: just like second, i tried flat library, but it does not give me response i wanted @subodhkalika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Array.map

You can use `.map` function to loop through the keys just to make it consistent and return a new object, the way you want it, then store in to the new highlights array.

### DEMO

```js
var jsonObject = { "highlights.id": [     "9ab80883-e8eb-4710-9818-e476fc32e356",     "824ff2a0-1f17-44b7-b99f-ce227af12ea7",     "4a9e35c5-e03f-41d6-a4b5-635b08bc1bbe",   ],   "highlights.key": ["0", "1", "2"],   "highlights.value": [     '16" Pedestal Fan',     "High Quality Metal Grill ",     "Heavy Duty Motor with 2000 RPM",   ],   "highlights.productId": [     "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f",     "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f",     "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f",   ],   "highlights.createdAt": [     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",   ],   "highlights.updatedAt": [     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",   ] };

const highlights = jsonObject['highlights.key'].map((v, i) => {
    return {
        "id": jsonObject['highlights.id'][i],
        "key": jsonObject['highlights.key'][i],
        "value": jsonObject['highlights.value'][i],
        "productId": jsonObject['highlights.productId'][i],
        "createdAt": jsonObject['highlights.createdAt'][i],
        "updatedAt": jsonObject['highlights.updatedAt'][i],
    };
})
console.log(highlights);
```

### Dynamic solution:

If you want it to be more dynamic you can loop through the keys of your JSON object as well

```js
var jsonObject = { "highlights.id": [     "9ab80883-e8eb-4710-9818-e476fc32e356",     "824ff2a0-1f17-44b7-b99f-ce227af12ea7",     "4a9e35c5-e03f-41d6-a4b5-635b08bc1bbe",   ],   "highlights.key": ["0", "1", "2"],   "highlights.value": [     '16" Pedestal Fan',     "High Quality Metal Grill ",     "Heavy Duty Motor with 2000 RPM",   ],   "highlights.productId": [     "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f",     "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f",     "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f",   ],   "highlights.createdAt": [     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",   ],   "highlights.updatedAt": [     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",     "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z",   ] };
const highlights = jsonObject['highlights.key'].map((v, i) => {
    const newObject = {};
    Object.keys(jsonObject).forEach((v) => {
        newObject[v.replace('highlights.','')] = jsonObject[v][i];
    });
    return newObject;
})
console.log(highlights);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it's not possible to convert into

```
highlights:[ {// id, key, value, productId}, {}, {}]
```

because there is an object inside your array `highlights`. You must declare an object key. I have an idea for your solution by using `Class` and `constructor`

```js
var object = {
  "highlights.id": ["9ab80883-e8eb-4710-9818-e476fc32e356", "824ff2a0-1f17-44b7-b99f-ce227af12ea7", "4a9e35c5-e03f-41d6-a4b5-635b08bc1bbe", ],
  "highlights.key": ["0", "1", "2"],
  "highlights.value": ['16" Pedestal Fan', "High Quality Metal Grill ", "Heavy Duty Motor with 2000 RPM", ],
  "highlights.productId": ["655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", ],
  "highlights.createdAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ],
  "highlights.updatedAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ]
}
var arr = []

class Highlights {
  constructor(id, key, value, productId, createdAt, updatedAt) {
    this.id = id;
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.productId = productId;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < object["highlights.id"].length; i++) {
  let highlights = new Highlights(object["highlights.id"][i], object["highlights.key"][i], object["highlights.value"][i],
    object["highlights.productId"][i], object["highlights.createdAt"][i], object["highlights.updatedAt"][i])

  arr.push(highlights);
}
//get all 
console.log(arr)
//get arr 0 ID
console.log(arr[0].id);
```

If you meant

```
highlights:[ {id:"a", key: "b", value: "c", productId: "d"}, {}, {}]
```

then my solution to you is...

```js
var object = {
  "highlights.id": ["9ab80883-e8eb-4710-9818-e476fc32e356", "824ff2a0-1f17-44b7-b99f-ce227af12ea7", "4a9e35c5-e03f-41d6-a4b5-635b08bc1bbe", ],
  "highlights.key": ["0", "1", "2"],
  "highlights.value": ['16" Pedestal Fan', "High Quality Metal Grill ", "Heavy Duty Motor with 2000 RPM", ],
  "highlights.productId": ["655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", ],
  "highlights.createdAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ],
  "highlights.updatedAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ]
}
var arr = []
for (i = 0; i < object["highlights.id"].length; i++) {
  arr.push({
    id: object["highlights.id"][i],
    key: object["highlights.key"][i],
    value: object["highlights.value"][i],
    productId: object["highlights.productId"][i],
    createdAt: object["highlights.createdAt"][i],
    updatedAt: object["highlights.updatedAt"][i]
  });
}
//get all arr
console.log(arr)
//get arr 0 ID
console.log(arr[0].id)
//or
console.log(arr[0]["id"])
```

The difference between class and object in this use case is naming convention such that object allows you to use `spacing for naming key` while you can't do that in `constructor` (either `_` or capital keys to make it easier to differentiate)

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE : While updating object in javascript, [.] where . is dynamic key without square bracket it will be a static key.**

```
let flattenHighlights = []
let flattenKeysObject = {}
for(let key of Object.keys(highlights)){
     let highlightKey = key.replace('highlights.','')
     {...flattenKeysObject, [highlightKey]:highlights[key]}
}
console.log("highlights : ", flattenKeysObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with iterate it through `data` array. If you want a simple answer, try this:

1. First way:

```js
let data = {
    "highlights.id": ["9ab80883-e8eb-4710-9818-e476fc32e356", "824ff2a0-1f17-44b7-b99f-ce227af12ea7", "4a9e35c5-e03f-41d6-a4b5-635b08bc1bbe", ],
    "highlights.key": ["0", "1", "2"],
    "highlights.value": ['16" Pedestal Fan', "High Quality Metal Grill ", "Heavy Duty Motor with 2000 RPM", ],
    "highlights.productId": ["655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", ],
    "highlights.createdAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ],
    "highlights.updatedAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ]
}

let newData = Array(data['highlights.id'].length).fill(null).map((d,index) => ({
  id: data['highlights.id'][index],
  key: data['highlights.key'][index],
  value: data['highlights.value'][index],
  productId: data['highlights.productId'][index],
//  createdAt: data['highlights.updatedAt'][index],
//  updatedAt: data['highlights.updatedAt'][index]
}));
console.log(newData);
```

---

2. Second way:

```js
let data = {
    "highlights.id": ["9ab80883-e8eb-4710-9818-e476fc32e356", "824ff2a0-1f17-44b7-b99f-ce227af12ea7", "4a9e35c5-e03f-41d6-a4b5-635b08bc1bbe", ],
    "highlights.key": ["0", "1", "2"],
    "highlights.value": ['16" Pedestal Fan', "High Quality Metal Grill ", "Heavy Duty Motor with 2000 RPM", ],
    "highlights.productId": ["655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", "655ea6af-9e5c-401e-b317-ea1fac55857f", ],
    "highlights.createdAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ],
    "highlights.updatedAt": ["2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", "2023-03-15T07:27:39.150Z", ]
}

let newData = Array(data['highlights.id'].length).fill(null).map((d,index) => {
  let obj = {};
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    obj[key.split('.')[1]] = data[key][index];
  });
  return obj;
}).map((d)=>{
  delete d['createdAt'];
  delete d['updatedAt'];
  return d;
});
console.log(newData);
```